# How to update a ULabel which is in a viewController from a custom UICollectionViewCell in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, uicollectionviewcell

I have a custom UICollectionViewCell which has buttons and images which feeds my collectionView. When a button is clicked I want to my label which serves as a counter to be updated

```
class MyCollectionCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    let btnRate: UIImageView = {
        let image = UIImageView()
        image.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        image.clipsToBounds = true
        image.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        image.alpha = 0
        return image
    }()
 
    let btnSmallOkRate: UIButton = {
        let btn = UIButton()
        btn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        btn.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        btn.setImage(UIImage(named: "OkIt"), for: .normal)
        btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(okItem), for: .touchUpInside)
        btn.alpha = 0
        return btn
    }()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        
        movieImage.addSubview(btnRate)
        contentView.addSubview(btnSmallOkRate)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            btnRate.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: movieImage.centerXAnchor),
            btnRate.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: movieImage.centerYAnchor),
            btnRate.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30),
            btnRate.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30),
            
            btnSmallOkRate.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: movieOverlay.leadingAnchor, constant: 20),
            btnSmallOkRate.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: movieOverlay.centerYAnchor),
            btnSmallOkRate.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20),
            btnSmallOkRate.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20)
        ])
    @objc func okItem(){
        btnSmallOkRate.alpha = 0
        removeOverlay.alpha = 0
        btnRate.alpha = 1
        btnRate.image = UIImage(named: "OkIt")
        Commons.userGlobalRate += 1
        GuestRateMovieView().lblRated.text = "\(Commons.userGlobalRate) rated"
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
}
```

In my viewController I have my label which is position at the top of the view

```
class GuestRateMovieView: UIViewController {
let lblRated: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.textColor = .black
        label.text = "0 rated"
        label.font = UIFont(name: String.circularStdBook, size: 14)
        return label
    }()
}
```

Comment: Is `GuestRateMovieView` the same view controller that has the collection view?

Comment: Yes GuestRateMovieView is the view controller

Comment: I know it's a view controller. I'm asking if it's the view controller that contains the collection view.

Comment: Yes it is the view controller that contains the collection view